# How to route root domain A record to a traffic manager with traffic manager endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I currently have 3 traffic managers, 1 entry point for our domain, which does geolocation routing to 2 other traffic managers. One global, one for the US.

These traffic managers are priority traffic managers which point to application gateways. By having the priority traffic managers, it allow us to have a 'failover' if one site / application gateway goes down.

The reason we have a application gateway in the different countries is to allow path manipulation so if the user is from the US, they get a /us path instead of a /.

I have configured our CNAMES like www. and blog. in the application gateways for both, global and US which works fine. I can point the CNAME records to the entry traffic manager no problem.

The problem I have having is pointing the A record root domain to the traffic manager. Since traffic managers don't have IP addresses, I get an error because in Azure, the root domain can be pointed at a traffic manager, but only one that uses external endpoints using a IP Address.

Has anyone else ran into this issue and have a way to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a root/apex domain to Azure Traffic Manager should be possible as it is integrated with Azure DNS. So, you should be able to create A record to ATM as shown below from Azure DNS,
[image]